# Is the Leibniz rule applicable to a derivative of expected value if derived by the random function?

Tags: probability-theory, analysis, expected-value

In an optimisation problem I have encountered the following expression:

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial f (x)} \int _0 ^1 g(x) \, f (x) \, d x
$$

with $g(x)$ being the probability density function on base 0 to 1.

I would be immensely grateful if you could tell me if I can apply the Leibniz rule here or not—and why. I am sceptical, because if I can, the expression becomes 1, and this seems too good to be true:

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial f (x)} \int _0 ^1 g(x) \, f (x) \, d x = 
\int _0 ^1 \frac{\partial}{\partial f (x)} \big( g(x) \, f (x) \big)\, d x =
\int _0 ^1 g(x) \, d x = 1
$$

Have a lovely day!

Comment: Leibniz rule for differentiation under the integral sign assumes that the integrand is continuously differentiable. Is that true here? I do not know anything about $f$ and $g$, so could you please provide context?

Comment: That definite integral is actually a constant.

Comment: Thank you for your considerations!
$f(x)$ and $g(x)$ should be as general as possible, but we can assume that they are well-behaved.
@VIVID: I think the integral is constant with regard to $x$, or if $f(x)=x$ but it will change with a change in $f(x)$. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Nebukor If $F(x) = \int g(x)f(x)dx$ then $\int_0^1 g(x)f(x)dx = F(1) - F(0)$. I think $F(1)-F(0)$ is not a (non-constant) function of $f$. Do you agree?

Comment: Thanks for the rapid response! But I can't quite agree yet, because I think I can't choose to make $F(x)$ as in the overall optimisation, f(x) endogenous. If I go for the substitution, shouldn't it rather be $F(f(x))$?